# Catching Python exceptions using 'expect' method?

Tags: python

```
import sys
try:
        file = open("words.txt")
expect(IOError):

if file:
    print "%s" % file
else:
    print "Cant the %s file" % "words.txt"
```

this gives me an a error -

```
File "main.py", line 4 
    expect(IOError):
    SyntaxError: invaild syntax
```

What im going wrong/ how do you fix this

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Your question ("how do you fix this?") is vague.  "Fix this" could mean anything.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, it is except as in exception:

For instance:

```
except IOError:
    print "Error opening file!"
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are trying to handle exceptions. In that case, use **except**, not **expect**. In any case except is **not a function**, rather it precedes a block of error handling code. When using files, you may want to look at the **with statement** and **try-except-finally**. The correction to your code is-

```
import sys
try:
        file = open("words.txt")
except IOError:
      #Handle error
      pass
if file:
    print "%s" % file
else:
    print "Cant the %s file" % "words.txt"
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's `except`. Read [this](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [except](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#except). The [error handling](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html) part of the python tutorial explains it well.

-John

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> try:
...     f = open('words.txt')
... except IOError:
...     print "Cant the %s file" % "words.txt"
... else:
...     print "%s" % f
```